# Control Launcher option in android

Tags: android, android-launcher

I have created an app for visually impaired. When the user clicks on Physical Home button I am getting the launcher dialog box working perfectly fine.

Instead of inbuilt dialog box. I would like to get my activity screen which has the list of launchers so that user can select and open any launcher according the requirement.

For e.g.

If the user has two launcher

1. Launcher (Default)
2. MyApp launcher

On myactivity screen it should show up launcher and myApp and user should able select anything required.

Is this possible? if so how? Can somebody direct me to that page as a start?

Thanks!

Comment: display an alertdailog when your application starts with two buttons and oncliclk on those buttons start appropriate activity

Answer (score 0):

When the user presses the home button, the system is attempting to fulfil the `android.intent.category.HOME` intent. The dialog pop up is there when there is no user preference, the system will always have control of this UI.

What you could do is fulfil this intent yourself, and be the default launcher - even if your launcher's action is to provide the means to launch another launcher?

Comment: According to other forum and questions.. I cannot programmatically select default launcher as mylauncher?

Comment: No - The user would need to select your launcher as the default, but it'd work from then on in?

Comment: True but what if he doesn't select the default?

Comment: I'm afraid that's out of your control. You'd just need to suggest it in your instructions